# Sum values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, scipy

I am trying to sum values for a slice of a dictionary with class int values.

Here is my code:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

inventories = 4 # states
mu = 1 # value for lambda
prob = []
for i in range(inventories):
     prob.append(poisson.pmf(i, mu))

Transitions = {}
for i in range(inventories):
    for j in range(inventories-1,-1,-1):
        if i - j < 0:
            Transitions[0,i,j] = 0
        elif j <> 0:
            Transitions[0,i,j] = prob[i-j]
        elif j == 0:
            Transitions[0,i,j] = 1
```

If you run this I am trying to get the last line of code to sum over all j for each i.  I am a MATLAB coder so I am used to matrices and I think this is screwing me up.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Since you're already using Scipy AND you say you have more experience in Matlab, why not use a matrix instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks for response.  I thought of this and I think I will replicate problem as matrix.  But I really want to learn Python and I thought this a good way to understand dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps you know can enlighten me as to which would be better if this were to be scaled up significantly?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you missing a line? I don't see any summing here....

Comment: Yes thats just it - I don't know how to do the summing so I put a "1" as a place holder.   Should have been more clear upfront.

Comment: Dictionaries can be really useful. Tuples-as-dictionary-keys can occasianally be useful, but in this situation, where you want to sum over dictionary items depending on a position in their tuple-key, it really isn't very practical. Someone might show you how you could do it anyway, but it will be awkward and inefficient. On the other hand, a scipy/numpy matrix or array will give you direct access to all items for which i==x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the dictionary using list comprehensions:

```
>>> l=[v for (k,v) in Transitions.iteritems() if k[1] == 3]
>>> sum(l)
1.9196986029286058
```

This gives the sum over j for i = 3. To sum over i, replace `k[1]` with `k[2]`.

All told, list comprehensions like this are pretty speedy, though I can't say how they rank against scipy matrices.

You can also get fancy:

```
>>> l=[sum([v for (k,v) in Transitions.iteritems() if k[1] == i]) for i in range(1,4,1)]
>>> l
[1.3678794411714423, 1.7357588823428847, 1.9196986029286058]
```

This gives you the sum over each row.

---

So the above is based on my misunderstanding of the question. Sorry, OP :(

I think you want to replace the line with something like:

```
Transitions[0,i,j] = sum([Transitions[0,i,k] for k in range(1,i+1,1)])
```

Comment: A numpy matrix (or even a list of lists) would be much better here. There's no way to slice a dict with this structure without visiting every element.

Comment: Sure, but he's looking to learn the language, as per his comments. Presumably he/she can decide which is more efficient/best meets his/her needs by doing some benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has potential but I can't replicate the result.  Where exactly did you place this line of code?  I want to actually replace the value "1" in my last line of code with the sum over j > 0.

Comment: Ben, Worked like a charm.  As a first time member of this forum I am very happy with community responses and timeliness.  Thanks for all the feedback